# How to change button text from read more to some other text in post category and in post wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to change the post link text in post-category of read more?
Also how to change related post text also its read more **button**
[Post Image For Refrence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erKMH.jpg)

I tried adding code in post-single.php also funtions.php

```
// Customizes read more link in excerpts
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
   global $post;
     return ‘ <strong> … on the edge of your seat? Read more! </strong> ‘; //you 
     can change this text to whatever you like
}
add_filter(‘excerpt_more’, ‘new_excerpt_more’);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you are showing, your snippet will work for the default read more, shown as Classic in the codex.

See how your snippet is not showing anywhere on the button?

Lets try this one.

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
global $post;
return ' <a class="moretag btn btn-primary" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read More »</a>'; //Change to suit your needs
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more' );
```

This should at least take you to a point where you can debug, but be noted, it can be very theme-specific. An URL, if you are able to provide it can help a ton.

Comment: Should I add this snippet in functions.php?